# Winsock: как проверять статус отправки WSASend и приема WSARecv данных?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock

Возник такой вопрос, а как можно проверять "статус" отправки исходящего буфера с WSASend и заполнения приемного буфера с WSARecv ? А то может удаленный сервер завис или соединения разорвалось (актуально для WSASend) - а клиент условно ждет, когда же произойдет передача или прием.

1)Если с WSARecv - можно сделать такой костыль: то есть перед указанием буфера для WSARecv предварительно обнулить его и в другом потоке периодически проверять заполнение буфера, то есть если нули заполняются, то прием данных идет.

2)То с отслеживанием передачи данных с помощью WSASend непонятно, как можно сделать условный костыль, ну передал я указатель на буфер, который нужно отправить в функцию WSASend и все, ниче не проверить.

Может, кто может пару идей подсказать ?

Comment: а так никто не делает. Если Вам интересно, что сервер не завис, делайте таймауты и пинг-понг пакеты.

Comment: @KoVadim, я думал о тайм-аутах, но проблема, как мне кажется в тайм-аутах может быть в том, какое значение ставить. Ведь  я могу передавать всего пару килобайт на сервер и поставить условно тайм-аут 30 секунд, а могу передавать файл в 100 Мб - тут уже глупо ставить тай-аут, плюс время зависит еще от скорости линии.

Comment: о да. tcp протокол на самом деле решает большинство подобных проблем. можно поднастроить keep-alive и оно уже решит кучу проблем (по факту он настроен на разрыв соединений с очень большим интервалом)

Comment: @KoVadim, вы это имеете ввиду - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-keepalive ?

Comment: да да. если правильно все настроите, то оно само будет ганять спец-пакеты по сети с заданным интервалом и проверять, живо ли подключение. Правда это мало защищает от зависшего приложения, но помогает отследить разрыв. Я тестил когда то давно (более 10 лет назад) в локальной сети. Работало достаточно нормально.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, проблему с зависшем приложением - эта штука действительно решить не может.